Why isn't adding html style attributes via useHead the same as adding custom CSS in Nuxt?
In Nuxt 3 (3.10.3) I am trying to dynamically load Google fonts based on a query parameter in the URL.
Load font in onBeforeMount based on that route query parameter:
onBeforeMount(() => {
    useHead({
        link: [
            {
                rel: 'preconnect',
                href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com'
            },
            {
                rel: 'preconnect',
                href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
                crossorigin: '',
            },
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                href: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${route.query.font}:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap`
            }
        ]
    })
})

Set the font-family in <template>:
<ClientOnly>
    <component is="style">
        html {
            font-family: {{ font }}, 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
        }
    </component>
</ClientOnly>

This works fine, but I would expect this to work as well with useHead().
It works well when I add the styling (add font-family rule) via a custom <style> tag, but does not if I use the useHead() Nuxt composable to set the htmlAttrs.style there. What difference is there in these two approaches? There's just no where I can put the useHead composable (onload of the font script, onMounted, anywhere in script setup) to make this work without having the CSS in template.

Lifecycles, context, parsing etc. Nuxt is a complex app (as everything is lately) so it's not a trivial thing to do overall, hence the small difference in result here.
